# What is the significance of Acts 10:13, 11:7 "make sacrificial slaughter"

Tags: greek, acts, word-study

The verses say,

> και εγενετο φωνη προς αυτον αναστας πετρε θυσον και φαγε
>   and became a sound/voice to him arise Peter make-sacrificial-slaughter and eat

Comment: Is the Tyson meat company named after these two verses?

Comment: For those who may be wondering where you got this gloss: [θύω](http://stephanus.tlg.uci.edu/lsj/#eid=50966&context=lsj&action=hw-list-click)

Comment: I am a novice at koine Greek, which I got a lousy C grade for introductory koine Greek in Bible school. I am wondering, what the significance is, if any. Hebrew is simpler and more exciting.

Answer (score 1):

While θυσον is used to speak of killing an animal as a sacrifice in other contexts I don't see any reason to see anything here other than killing them. I say this because:

- Peter is said to be hungry when he went into a trance but there is no context provided for a sacrificial event
- Peter is not a Levitic priest, nor does he protest about not being one while he does protest about not *eating* unclean foods
- Peter would not have any of the required paraphernalia: a temple, an altar, priestly garb, a blood catcher, burning coals, etc.
- the word has extant usage for just "killing":

> Isa 22:13 (Brenton LXX)  And behold joy and gladness, slaying oxen,
>   and **killing** sheep, eating flesh, and drinking wine: let us eat and
>   drink; for to morrow we shall die.

So I would answer: "None".

Well, not "none" (that's a bit absolutist of me) but nothing significant or germane.

Also, we are not told that the animals were unclean. They should be understood to be unclean seeing that Peter is chastised for calling clean animals unclean.

Comment: I don't think you can connect the corollaries of a Hebrew word to a Greek word. They are not the same word. That is like equating the word *murder* to *kill*, to prohibit against eating animal meat.

Comment: "Peter is not a Levitic priest" - doesn't Christian doctrine associate a believer to priestliness ? I was wondering if Acts 10, 11 is somehow correlated to 1 Peter 2:9.

Comment: I edited the text to show that the Isaiah verse was taken from the LXX, not the Hebrew.  1 Peter 2:9 has in mind offering "praises" not animals, per the context.

Comment: I voted you up, even though I think the septuagint is crapola, for the very fact that you helped reinforce the misalignment between the masoret and the septuagint. However, I would love to have a response that ignores the septuagint but uses the masoret.

Comment: @BlessedGeek  There are several:  Luk 15:23  Bring the fattened calf and **kill** it, and let's eat and celebrate!