# Do Acts 10 and 11 invalidate the prohibition against consuming blood?

Tags: acts, law

In relation to my previous question, [What is the significance of Acts 10:13, 11:7 "make sacrificial slaughter"](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/20182/what-is-the-significance-of-acts-1013-1117-make-sacrificial-slaughter).

> o δε πετρος ειπεν μηδαμως κυριε οτι ουδεποτε εφαγον παν κοινον η ακαθαρτον
>
> and yet Peter said not-at-all lord that have yet I eaten any/(every?) common or unclean.

If the blood in animal meat is considered unclean and common, would these passages invalidate Genesis 9:4,5 ?

How do Acts 10, 11 invalidate

- Acts 15:29
- אך בשר בנפשו דמו לא תאכלו
  but meat with its life its blood not shall you eat

Do "unclean and common" equate to "life its blood" ? How ?

- ואך את דמכם לנפשתיכם אדרש
  מיד כל חיה אדרשנו
  but yet of your blood of your lives I will inquire
  consequence/from-hand of all living shall I inquire of him

Does this mean that Christianity affirming the prohibition against knowingly "eating food offered to idols" is also no longer valid?

I am not quoting the Deuteronomy passages because, clearly the passages in Acts intend to invalidate Deuteronomy. But question remains, how do you allow yourself to have a beef steak barbecue with blood oozing from the meat, without violating Christian biblical principles?

I know there are verses in Galations et al, that say, not to let anyone judge you by what you eat - but saying "Do not let anyone judge you by your reckless life" does not encourage you to live a reckless life.

Comment: edited typo: תוכלו should be תאכלו

Comment: As worded, this reads like a doctrinal question, which is off-topic here.  To fix this, I think you need to ask if the author *intended* to invalidate Genesis, instead of asking if the passage *does* so.  And, you certainly should remove the "how do you allow yourself to have a beef steak" bit and the stuff that follows, which is completely off-topic - no one here cares how individuals justify their actions in their own head.

Comment: "how do you allow yourself" under common-sense means, "with what scriptural basis".

Comment: which remains a doctrinal question ("what verse(s) are used to support this"), not a question of what the author of Acts meant in this verse.

Comment: Strong argument.

Comment: Strong or Strong's?