# Does Peter's Vision in Acts 10 Imply Blood Consumption?

Tags: greek, acts, septuagint, peter

A general but off-topic question was posed related to this thought. See here:
[What is the significance of Acts 10:13, 11:7 "make sacrificial slaughter"](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/20182/what-is-the-significance-of-acts-1013-1117-make-sacrificial-slaughter)

Acts 10:10-16 describes Peter's vision of animals of all sorts being placed before him with the command to kill and eat. Peter's statement in verse 14 seems to imply that his concern was the unclean status of the animals in front of him. He does not state anything about blood.

That being said, is there any implication of blood consumption in the wording of verse 13?

> καὶ ἐγένετο φωνὴ πρὸς αὐτόν ἀναστάς Πέτρε θῦσον καὶ φάγε

Comment: I cannot see any way in which the words of verse 13 could be understood to include what is suggested.

Comment: @NigelJ It doesn't explicitly say - I agree. I am trying to determine if there might or might not be anything implicit. An explicit OT reference, I Sam. 14:32, is what comes to mind as a point of reference.

Comment: I would add that under normal circumstances killing and then immediately eating any animal would result in blood consumption, and no mention is made of preparation or cooking either - however, I'm somewhat hesitant to push a vision for those kind of details.

Comment: I've heard deer hunters talk about bleeding the deer immediately after killing it so that the meat lasts longer before getting it home.

Comment: >Kosher preparation of foods requires that, to remove the blood, which may not be consumed, meat is soaked in water, carefully salted with coarse salt, and washed. Further, specific veins must be removed. Liver in particular must be cut, washed, salted, and broiled over a fire. Eggs with a spot of blood in them are deemed forbidden.

Neusner, J., Avery-Peck, A. J., & Green, W. S. (Eds.). (2000). In The encyclopedia of Judaism (Vol. 3, p. 1066). Leiden; Boston; Köln: Brill.

Comment: However, we have to ask if this kosher practice was already in place in the first century, or was bleeding the animal enough at that time?

Comment: @PerryWebb Thanks for the input. I've done the same thing myself in hunting. If the kosher practice was indeed practiced at this time, the vision itself already countermands the dietary restrictions already, so I would expect it to countermand the kosher-specific practice as well. At this point, I think it is clear that it is simply indeterminate. The more I consider it, the more the focus seems to be the classification of the animals rather than the manner of consumption.

Comment: Down voter - curious about the DV. This question may not be profound, and the answer may simply be 'no', but it follows the guidelines for a good question as far as I can tell - maybe I'm mistaken though. I would appreciate a comment so it can be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is no. You see, although the Lord commanded Peter to kill and eat, Peter response sharply by saying that he has epnever eaten anying unclean. (NIV Acts 10:14) Then the Lord replies "Do not call anything impure what God has made clean" (NIV Acts 10:15b). This is metaphorical, and God is not actually telling Peter to kill and eat, but rather relating to his work with the Gentiles.

This is also a visions, Peter couldn't have ate anything.

Regarding the Greek translation, the word φάγε is a command to eat, but does not neccessarilly connotate the eating of blood. However, since I am not a Greek scholar, I could be wrong.

Finally, according to the Old Testament, all Jewish sacrfices required the draining of the blood and cooked before consumption. (Leviticus 17, 1 Samuel 14:33) Peter, still being a devout Jew, would probably cook it and drain the blood.